# Grails: generate-controller * is working but create-controller * is not working

Tags: grails, grails-2.4

I need the scaffold functionality. For that instead of doing create-controller and manually adding the

```
def scaffold = true
```

to each controller, I installed templates and added

```
def scaffold = true
```

inside src/templates/artifacts/Controller.groovy file as below.

```
@artifact.package@class @artifact.name@ {
    def scaffold = true
```

}

The interesting fact is create-* only works for this case.

**Question:** Instead of create-controller *class_name* one by one, is there a way to create-controller * functionality like generate-controller *?

Comment: You should use `create-scaffold-controller`. If you add that line to your regular controller template, all controllers will be scaffolded by default. Using a wildcard ("uber-generate") was something that was added for the generate scripts, but I assume not for the `create-controller` and `create-scaffold-controller` scripts because they generate such trivial classes, it's easy enough to just create them by hand.

Comment: Burt which file you are referring to? if it the same i have mentioned above then it will not work. This template only be used in case of create-controller command.

Comment: `create-controller` is for non-scaffolded controllers where you define all of the actions and it's created from the `templates/artifacts/Controller.groovy` template. If you want a scaffolded controller, use `create-scaffold-controller` which creates a controller using `templates/artifacts/ScaffoldingController.groovy`.